# Spring bean order in collection. Deterministic?

Tags: java, spring, jvm, classloader

In our company we notified that on different servers order of beans in autowired collection is different, but on the same machine it's always the same (after each deployment). How spring or maybe classLoader arrange beans that are equivalent? in our case we have 2 implementations of some interface. And that implementations are injected with collection in some place. And on host 1 it's always A,B in injected collection and on host 2 it's always B,A.

So it looks like it's deterministic, but different on different machines. Can anybody confirm that? What it depends on? I cannot find any information about that.

EDIT: I listed files on HD without any sort with ls -U and noticed that on host 1 classes are in order A,B and on host 2 in order B,A. Can anybody confirm that this is the reason? So then I will search why this order is different on different machines :) (.war with classes is the same, downloaded directly from nexus repository)

Comment: Consider putting a bounty on existing posts instead of re-asking the same question.

Answer (score -2):

In short, you want to know the default sequence of spring bean instantiation.

There are many algorithms involved during bean instantiation like dependency resolution, explicit dependency configuration (@DependsOn) etc. When a bean doesn't fall in any if...else then it becomes the default instantiation sequence. So, no one guarantees the default sequence of bean instantiation although we can imply bean instantiation order through configurations.

Since no document talks clearly about the default sequence of spring bean instantiation. I consider it arbitrary, if you figure out a pattern you can go ahead with that but dont make any logical implementation depending upon this pattern because it is not guaranteed.

Comment: This is legacy code. I'm not implementing anything basing on that order. I just want to know how it's working.

Comment: you "how it's working" mean to me is "default sequence of spring bean instantiation" and I explained it in the answer :)

Comment: so what is "default instantiation sequence" is this two beans are instantianed by autoscanning and no other beans have references on them? Only one reference is this autowired collection with them.